# Apple Developer and Distribution Certification Expiring - Proper Way to Regenerate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I received an email from Apple saying that my iOS Distribution Certificate will expire in 30 days. When I went to the Developer Portal I also saw that my personal Development certificate will also expire in 30 days. However, the docs are very confusing and most of the answers online on how to fix this are very old. So the questions I have are:

1. I am using XCode to 'Automatically manage signing'. Does this mean that it automatically renews these certificates when they go to expire? Or does this have anything to do with managing the expiration of these? Does it regenerate one of the certs and not the other? It is very unclear what exactly the automatic managing actually does in this situation.
2. If XCode does not automatically renew these certs, what is the proper procedure in doing so that will not impact development and updates sent to the App Store? Should I generate new certs for both iOS Distribution and Development before I revoke the old ones? Or revoke the old ones first and then regenerate new ones? Again, vague on the procedure.
3. These certs are also being used for PushNotification profile and keys, which also appear to expire in 30 days in the Developer portal. Is there anything that needs to be done with these or does XCode also take care of this?
4. Is there a way (either in XCode or the Developer Portal) to see which certs are actually being used and which ones are stagnant (may have been probably generated for testing purposes)? Again, it is really hard to determine which certs I need to worry about expiring and which ones aren't even being used.